# Horizontally centering some li's inside of a ul

Tags: css

I'm having an issue with centering some `li`'s that are inside of a `ul` element. Here is the relevant code:

```
ul.nav {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav li {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}

#government {
  clear: left;
}
```

I've been trying various things to make it work like making the `li`'s have `text-align: center;` or giving them `margin: 0 auto;` but nothing seems to be working. I've spent hours trying to figure out the problem, so any help would be very much appreciated. Here is a screenshot of what my situation looks like:

[image]

I'm trying to get the `li`'s to be horizontally centered inside that ul. I can't just do the math and set the margin because the width will  be dyanmic and probably won't be the same for each li.

Comment: so you want them to look just like in your screen shot (that is two rows, two items in each row) but not stuck to the left?

Comment: Yes user907860, that's right.

Comment: You should make a fiddle.  Just the css is not useful.

Comment: generally, the problem is that you are using the `float` property, and horizontal alignment is intended for inline elements, that is text, spans and those which have display inline or inline-block etc. You can still manage to align a floated element with the help of some wrappers, but I would suggest you to use either display:inline or dispaly:inline-block properties for the li elements

Comment: If I were to use `inline-block` instead, how would I get two rows without having the ability to clear?

Comment: can you insert a <br> element between the pairs of the li elements?

Comment: @meh_programmer then how about setting a smaller width for the `ul` element? Either `width` or `max-width` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should give you a good start:

```
ul.nav {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center; /* to center horizontally child inline elements */
}

.nav li {
  display: inline-block; /* Set to inline-block instead of float: left */
  width: 300px;
}
```

**Update**

To get into to rows, make your `ul` element have a smaller width.

e.g.

```
ul.nav {
  width: 800px; /* Smaller width */
  margin: 0 auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center; /* to center horizontally child inline elements */
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bbat8azL/)

Comment: This helped me get a lot closer to my desired result, thanks. I just need to figure out how to get it into two rows now.

Comment: @meh_programmer I have answered your question in the comments.